# Is is appropriate to specify what a general studies degree was in?

Tags: mathematics, undergraduate, bachelor, psychology

I graduated with a B.S. in Electrical Engineering back in May. However, due to some extra credits I also have a general studies degree, the diploma for which simply states "Bachelor of Science" and nothing else.

For resumes and general discussion is it appropriate to say what subjects contributed to the general studies degree? And how would should I describe it on my resume (right now it just says "Bachelor of Science").

For example, I took psychology and math courses that contributed to the general studies degree, so is it accurate to say that the degree is "a general studies degree focused on mathematics and psychology".

Comment: The fact that your diploma doesn't list a concentration doesn't matter.  Bachelor of Arts diplomas (in the US) typically read only "Bachelor of Arts", leaving the major unstated.  Nevertheless, it is entirely appropriate for a BA holder to list their major in their resume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice:

*B.S. Electrical engineering

*B.S. General studies (math, psychology concentrations)

List them both, with the EE first--it is the one you would list if you could only list one, right?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I usually tell people only about the EE degree, but wanted to be more descriptive about the B.S. General studies. But yes, I would list the EE if I could only list one.

I like your answer, it gives me a good way to put it on resume. I'll wait 24 hours before accepting.

Answer (score 1):

If you are applying somewhere where mathematics or psychology is relevant, and you have a substantial amount of credits therein, then I recommend listing:

- B.S. in electric engineering
- B.S. in general studies (with m credits mathematics, p credits psychology)

I would presume that studies in mathematics would be favourable in most engineering contexts, but psychology might not be particularly interesting, so you might want to include math most of the time but consider omitting psychology. But sometimes it might be the other way around, or both or neither might be relevant.

Indicating the amount of credits is more specific and takes no more space than the alternatives, which is why I would prefer it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do that, especially if there was a "named" concentration. I doubt that it is necessary, but wouldn't be unusual to list it. But somewhere in your CV you should probably indicate that you have studied specific things.

But don't make it seem like you have a math degree (or even a "minor") unless you actually do. the descriptive phrasing you suggest seems appropriate.

There are a lot of ways to include such information in your CV, but it is best to include it somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The thing with the math classes I took is that I have more than enough credits for a math minor, but instead of listing it as minor the advisor and I decided to move it within the general studies degree.